# Python for loop returns only first element

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, pubmed

I'm trying to extract Pubmed IDs from Pubmed URLs, using https://pypi.org/project/pymed/.

Problem: Despite proper inputs all throughout my for loop, my "pubmed query" is apparently being performed only on the first iteration? Please help.

```
url_list = pd.Series of URLs, dtype='str'
ID_list = list(range(0, len(url_list)))

for i in url_list:
    spider = Pubmed("MyTool", my_email)
    url = url_list.iloc[i].to_string(index=False)
    print(url) #CORRECTLY ITERATES

    if re.search(pattern, url):

        lookup = spider.query(url) #Unique <class itertools.chain object>
        results = list(lookup) #Unique <'pymed.article.PubMedArticle' object>

        ID = results.pop().pubmed_id
        #OR
        ID = results[0].pubmed_id
        print(ID) #RETURNS ONLY THE FIRST ID

        ID_list[i] = ID

    else:
        ID_list[i] = None

    print("Extracted " + url + " with ID: " + ID)
```

I've tried settings the spider and lookup vars to None at the end of the whole loop, as well as using "del VAR" on both of them.

Nothing gives. For whatever reason, the spider.query() method is only pulling from the first url it is fed. Note that I also tried putting the Pubmed() spider outside the for loop, where it probably should go, but this was me trying to be thorough.

Thanks so much for the help, and I apologize for any issues reproducing this, or with anything stylistic that causes you pain and suffering.

Comment: I'm confused. If `i` is a URL (string), how can it be used as a list index?

Comment: You'll get the behavior you see if `re.search(pattern, url)` fails for all the rest of the URLs.

Comment: @Barmar, it definitely doesn't fail for everything. I was failing previously, and I would get `ID_list` = array full of None

@BallpointBen, `i` is the index, I'm assigning `url` to be the element of `url_list` at position `i`..........at the end of the day, `url` is correct throughout the whole loop, in any iteration

Comment: What do you see if you put `print(url)` inside the `if`?

Comment: @Barmar I see the correct url, as stated. I've gone through all options, the issue has to lie with how I'm interfacing with or implementing the spider or the query itself

Comment: Unless `spider.query()` ignores its argument, I can't see any way this could be happening.

Comment: Me neither. I tried looking through the source code from PyMed, and it seems pretty straightforward. I definitely didn't find anything to do with persistence? I'm thinking it might be doing some strange in-place appending, but I've also tested the length of `results` in each iteration, and it is always the single result that I queried. At the very least, I should be successfully producing a fresh instance of both the spider AND the query, so I really don't know where to go from here. Thanks for still trying to help!

Comment: Since you're creating a new `PubMed` instance each time through the loop, I don't see how it could be remembering the previous query.

Comment: Not that it matters, but why don't you use `ID_list.append(ID)` instead of preloading the list?

Comment: Just a newbie mistake. Thanks for the pointer! PS: It didn't magically fix it, I was hopeful ;)

Comment: Could it be with my data structure? Is there any simpler way I could loop through items? I tried a numpy array, but that didn't work either.